# Error changing position a Checkbox in XML

Tags: android, checkbox, casting, position

I am getting an error when trying to implement a **Custom Spinner Multi Selection**. I get ONLY an error when changing the position Checkbox in XML (I want to put the Checkbox to right).

**ERROR**

```
10-15 11:42:17.238: E/AndroidRuntime(29962): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.widget.CheckBox
10-15 11:42:17.238: E/AndroidRuntime(29962):    at com.dropdownlistdemo.DropDownListAdapter.getView(DropDownListAdapter.java:68)
```

**ERROR LINE**

```
holder.chkbox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
```

**XML OK**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkbox"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/SelectOption"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:textColor="@color/rojo" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**XML FAIL**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/SelectOption"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:textColor="@color/rojo" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkbox"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**JAVA**

```
public class DropDownListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private ArrayList<String> mListItems;
private LayoutInflater mInflater;
private TextView mSelectedItems;
private static int selectedCount = 0;
private static String firstSelected = "";
private ViewHolder holder;
private static String selected = "";

public static String getSelected() {
    return selected;
}

public void setSelected(String selected) {
    DropDownListAdapter.selected = selected;
}

public DropDownListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> items,
        TextView tv) {
    mListItems = new ArrayList<String>();
    mListItems.addAll(items);
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    mSelectedItems = tv;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mListItems.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int arg0) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int arg0) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.drop_down_list_row, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.SelectOption);
        holder.chkbox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.tv.setText(mListItems.get(position));

    final int position1 = position;

    holder.chkbox.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });

    if(DropDownListDemo.checkSelected[position])
        holder.chkbox.setChecked(true);
    else
        holder.chkbox.setChecked(false);     
    return convertView;
}

private class ViewHolder {
    TextView tv;
    CheckBox chkbox;
}
}
```

Comment: after changing, be sure You save the current code and clean Your Project..

Comment: Correct, my problem is solved